# CloudWatch : AWS logs showing 0 bytes even though there is data inside

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am working on a project, where i am streaming my data to AWS CloudWatch logs, via AWS Cloudwatch logs agent. I can see that there are log-groups getting created and there are logs inside it. Still AWS Cloudwatch is showing 0 bytes stored. Why is that?

This is an issue, as I am also streaming the data to our ES domain, and this stored data might be stopping it. Or am I doing something wrong? Here is a screenshot of the info :

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> storedBytes -> (long)
>
> The number of bytes stored.
>
> IMPORTANT: **Starting on June 17, 2019, this parameter will be
>   deprecated for log streams, and will be reported as zero**. This change
>   applies only to log streams. The storedBytes parameter for log groups
>   is not affected.

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/describe-log-streams.html)

Comment: My bad, it's log-groups, please check updated image, I have added a screenshot. Thank you. :-)